# c++ asio functions with completion handlers in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, boost-asio

I have simple question about Asio.

I wrote three classes `response`, `request` and `client`.

I want to put part of code in a loop for trying to connect.
There will be another loop for creating requests.

I can't imagine the proper place for the for loop.

Here's the code I have:

```
// typedef const HTTPResponse&(*Callback) (const HTTPRequest& request,
typedef void (*Callback)(const HTTPRequest &request, const HTTPResponse &response, const system::error_code &ec);

#include <fstream>
// const HTTPResponse& handler(const HTTPRequest& request,
void handler(const HTTPRequest &request, const HTTPResponse &response, const system::error_code &ec) {
    if (ec == 0) {
        /*
        if res.status_code == 200:
            for chunk in res.iter_content(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) :
                buffer.write(chunk)
            Logger.info("Fetched {0} completed in {1}s".format(id, time.time() - start))
            if len(buffer.getbuffer()) <= 0 :
                Logger.info("Buffer for {0} is empty ".format(id))
            return buffer.getbuffer()
        else:
            Logger.warn("Request to {0} failed with error code : {1} ".format(url, str(res.status_code)))
        */

        std::ofstream outFile("image.bc5", std::ofstream::out, std::ofstream::binary);

        outFile << response.get_response().rdbuf();

        outFile.close();

    } else if (ec == asio::error::operation_aborted) {
        std::cout << "Request #" << request.get_id() << " has been cancelled by the user." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Request #" << request.get_id() << " failed! Error code = " << ec.value()
                  << ". Error message = " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
    return response; //////?????????????
}

#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

void create_tasks(const symbols_enum &symbol, date day) {
    int start = 0;

    if (is_dst(day)) {
        start = 1;
    }

    ostringstream oss;
    oss << symbol;
    std::string url_currency{ oss.str() };
    std::ostringstream().swap(oss); // swap m with a default constructed stringstream
    std::string url_year{ day.year() };

    stringstream ss_month;
    ss_month << setw(2) << setfill('0') << ((day.month().as_number()) - 1);
    string url_month{ ss_month.str() };
    std::stringstream().swap(ss_month); // swap m with a default constructed stringstream
    // std::string url_month{std::to_string((day.month().as_number()) - 1)};

    stringstream ss_day;
    ss_day << setw(2) << setfill('0') << day.day().as_number();
    string url_day{ ss_day.str() };
    std::stringstream().swap(ss_day); // swap m with a default constructed stringstream
    // std::string url_day{day.day()};

    std::string URL{ protocol_host_URL + "/" + "datafeed" + "/" + url_currency + "/" + url_year + "/" + url_month +
                     "/" + url_day + "/" };

    HTTPClient client;

    // std::shared_ptr<HTTPRequest> request = client.create_request(hour, URL);
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<HTTPRequest> > requests_variables;
    // for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i) {
    // std::string varname = "sol" + std::to_string(i);
    // variables[varname] = i * i;
    //}
    for (int hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
        stringstream ss_hour;
        ss_hour << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour;
        string url_hour{ ss_hour.str() };
        std::stringstream().swap(ss_hour); // swap m with a default constructed stringstream
        URL = URL + url_hour + "h_ticks.bi5";

        std::string request_name = "request_" + std::to_string(hour);
        requests_variables[request_name] = client.create_request(hour, URL);
        requests_variables[request_name]->set_callback(handler);
        requests_variables[request_name]->execute();

        /*
        for (int i : boost::irange(0, ATTEMPTS))
            {
            try
                {
                    requests_variables[request_name]->execute();
                }
            catch (system::system_error &e)
                {
                    std::cout << "Error occured! Error code = " << e.code()
                    << ". Message: " << e.what();
                    return e.code().value();
                }
            }
        */
    }
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get]


            return tasks;
}
```

The code in comments is guessed place for the loop.

There might be python code, I am trying to mimic python asynchronous code and this code in this place "if the right place" will be converted after words.

I do not need translation to c++, I just need help to determine where to put for loop for trials in this code which uses completion handlers.
The asio code from book Boost Asio C++.

If the for loop code should be in class `request` or `response` or `client`, tell me.

If any one needs full code, let me know. I'm afraid I'll be posting to much "irrelevant code" otherwise :)

Comment: with boost asio asynchronous behavior, when the connect handler is called with an error code, start a retry timer, when that expires restart the connection.

Comment: good way to avoid for loop from main thread and depend on timers from io_service thread....but i ask about a way to make for loop from main thread ...i always see handlers returning void....can handlers return other values or shared pointers to response,to transfer them from io_service thread to main thread???...thanks for your reply

Comment: You loop from the completion routine.  There is no 'for loop'.

Comment: thanks  for your reply..i have a feeling that completion handlers must return void...is this true?or it can return shared pointer....in this case i can return pointer to response class and use it to loop...does it need mutex or any other thing ?this is because the ioservice is ran in different thread???

Comment: completion handlers can return anything, you use boost bind to attach the additional parameters, such as the buffer pointer etc..